# Counting digits of numbers

Tags: c, comparative-review, integer

> Write a program that loops prompting for positive or zero integers of
>   data type long. Then the number of digits the integer consists of (in
>   decimal representation) should be printed to stdout. Entering a
>   negative number immediately stops the program. Output examples: 0 has
>   1 digit. 999 has 3 digits. etc.

(And I think that I am not allowed to use any finished helpful function in any C library. It is just 'plain' C coding or so. I don't know how to describe it. We haven't learned arrays, strings etc. yet)

I heard the tips and have already adjusted it in the code below, so this is v2.

**Questions:**

I found two solutions yet to get this exercise/program 'working'. You can see it in v2 and v3, I've posted below.

I use VS 2017, i.e. when I 'Start without debugging' (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), then the CMD will be closed immediately, but when I go to Project-Properties/Linker/System and choose "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) at SubSystem, the CMD-window stays.

**Now the comparison between v2 and v3:**

I.e. when I use v2 I do not need to set a specific "SubSystem" as I told you before. I think it is because of `getchar()` in the `while()` is waiting for an input.

But I can also a while without 'EOF', which some guys on SO suggested before, so I made v3 that uses the while without `getchar()`. But to see my program, I have to set a "SubSystem" as I described before.

What solution is 'better'? And what would you improve?

Here is my C code v2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  long number = 0;
  int n = 0;
  int i = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    i = scanf_s("%ld", &number);

    if(i == 1)
    {
      if (number < 0)
      {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      else if (number == 0)
      {
        n = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        while (number != 0)
        {
          number /= 10;
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error - You've probably entered nothing."); //Idk what to write here, because the return-value of scanf_s can be less then 1 in this case so it must be zero, 
    }                                                     //if nothing is entered and somehow the program makes it into this else.

    printf("The number you've entered has %d digits.\n\n", n);
    n = 0;

  } while (getchar() != 'EOF');

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my C-Code v3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  long number = 0;
  int n = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int buffer = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    i = scanf_s("%ld", &number);

    buffer = number;

    if(i == 1)
    {
      if (number < 0)
      {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      else if (number == 0)
      {
        n = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        while (number != 0)
        {
          number /= 10;
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Error - You've probably entered nothing."); //Idk what to write here, because the return-value of scanf_s can be less then 1 in this case so it must be zero, 
    }                                                     //if nothing is entered and somehow the program makes it into this else.

    printf("The number you've entered has %d digits.\n\n", n);
    n = 0;

  } while (buffer >= 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no strings in C, and arrays don't act like arrays in other languages. Go into C expecting that the language will give you nothing, and you won't be disappointed.

Comment: `while (getchar() != 'EOF');` probably doesn't do what you think it does. Multicharacter constants aren't what you want there.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Do you mean that C give me nothing in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possibility that user may enter invalid characters at input. If that's the case, subsequent calls to `scanf()` fail, as these characters remain in buffer of input stream, thus printing *error message* infinitely.

You can use construct like the *one below* to avoid that. It looks like this may serve you better based on the requirement.

```
while (true)
{
    if (scanf("%ld",&input) != 1 || input < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid input\n");  /* arbitrary */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        // rest of code 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've change that too. 

But another question: What do you think about those commands like exit(), goto, break etc.? I think these are called 'labels' and I heard that it is very bad to use them, because it isn't a good style or so.

Comment: What do you say about that? Should I change the code without using exit() here?